# Deploying SoftPhone layouts using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, migration-tool, call-center

Using the Metadata API/Force.com Ant Migration tool, how does one retrieve or deploy the SoftPhone Layouts for the Call Center?

By SoftPhone Layout, I mean that which can be found at https://login.salesforce.com/04n?skipSplash=1

Alternatively, I see in Chapter 8 of the [CTI Toolkit
Developer Guide (pdf)](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_cti_developer_guide_2.pdf), there is a way to call `describeSoftphoneLayout()` and *read* this layout information.  Is there any way to programmatically *update* this layout (not including a Selenium script or the like)?

Comment: Vote for my "idea" for this at https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LjP7AAK

Answer (score 1):

Because I haven't found anything close to an answer for even versioning SoftPhone Layouts, I've created [a tool that will pull your SoftPhone Layout](https://github.com/PolarisProject/softPhoneLayoutMaintainer/) so you can at least version it.  Ideally, you should add a hook to whenever you pull metadata, you can pull this, too.

This does not currently include a way to POST this data, because I have no idea how to do that outside of the Web UI (I suppose at worst, this can be a Selenium script.)

I'm not accepting this answer, but providing it as a resource.

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve or upload call centers you need to add the following to `package.xml`:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CallCenter</name>
</types>
```

This is the example of the `.callCenter` XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CallCenter xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <adapterUrl>/apex/DialerSidebarPage</adapterUrl>
    <customSettings>{"reqSoftphoneHeight":"400","reqUseApi":"true","reqSoftphoneWidth":"300"}</customSettings>
    <displayName>Demo Call Center Adapter Open CTI</displayName>
    <displayNameLabel>Display Name</displayNameLabel>
    <internalNameLabel>InternalName</internalNameLabel>
    <sections>
        <items>
            <label>CTI Adapter URL</label>
            <name>reqAdapterUrl</name>
            <value>/apex/DialerSidebarPage</value>
        </items>
        <items>
            <label>Use CTI API</label>
            <name>reqUseApi</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </items>
        <items>
            <label>Softphone Height</label>
            <name>reqSoftphoneHeight</name>
            <value>400</value>
        </items>
        <items>
            <label>Softphone Width</label>
            <name>reqSoftphoneWidth</name>
            <value>300</value>
        </items>
        <label>General Information</label>
        <name>reqGeneralInfo</name>
    </sections>
    <sections>
        <items>
            <label>Outside Prefix</label>
            <name>reqOutsidePrefix</name>
            <value>9</value>
        </items>
        <items>
            <label>Long Distance Prefix</label>
            <name>reqLongDistPrefix</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </items>
        <items>
            <label>International Prefix</label>
            <name>reqInternationalPrefix</name>
            <value>01</value>
        </items>
        <label>Dialing Options</label>
        <name>reqDialingOptions</name>
    </sections>
</CallCenter>
```

It should have `.callcenter` extension and being placed in `callCenters` folder of your deployment archive.

Comment: Does this include SoftPhone Layout?

Comment: It is includes only call center config